# Why does ImageFont.getsize() measure characters inconsistently when using monospaced fonts?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to calculate the width and height of the glyphs in a monospaced font (which I'd expect to be consistent), but `ImageFont.getsize()` returns different values given different single-character strings:

```
>>> from PIL import ImageFont
>>> font = ImageFont.truetype("consola.ttf", size=15)
>>> font.getsize(".")
(8, 12) 
>>> font.getsize("@")
(9, 15)
```

`ImageFont.getlength()`, on the other hand, *does* always return the same width for every character:

```
>>> font.getlength("@")
8.0
>>> font.getlength(".")
8.0
```

So what is `getsize()` measuring, and why is it different to `getlength()`?

Comment: The source code may be helpful, `https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/master/src/PIL/ImageFont.py` starting at line 375

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [ImageFont.py](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/master/src/PIL/ImageFont.py) file:

getlength():

> Returns length (in pixels with 1/64 precision) of given text when rendered in font with provided direction, features, and language. This is the amount by which following text should be offset. Text bounding box may extend past the length in some fonts, e.g. when using italics or accents. The result is returned as a float; it is a whole number if using basic layout.

getsize():

> Returns width and height (in pixels) of given text if rendered in font with provided direction, features, and language.

The file explains the difference as:

> Use :py:meth:`getlength()` to measure the offset of following text with 1/64 pixel precision.

What I understand from this is that `getlength()` returns the offset (space) between the current text and the following text, while `getsize()` returns the actual dimensions of the current (inputted) text.

From the Consola font family [website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/font-list/consolas):

> ... a monospaced font is specified. All characters have the same width ...

This means that each each character should be the same width, and each character should have the same space from the next. Which can be seen in the following script:

```
import PIL
from PIL import ImageFont
font = ImageFont.truetype("consola.ttf",size=15)
print(font.getsize("a"))
print(font.getsize("h"))
print(font.getsize("g"))
print(font.getsize("z"))
print(font.getsize("."))
print(font.getsize("@"))
print(font.getlength("a"))
print(font.getlength("h"))
print(font.getlength("g"))
print(font.getlength("z"))
print(font.getlength("."))
print(font.getlength("@"))
```

Which outputs:

```
(8, 12)
(8, 12)
(8, 15)
(8, 12)
(8, 12)
(9, 15)
8.0
8.0
8.0
8.0
8.0
8.0
```

Almost every character has a width of 8 and an offset of 8, however their heights were different because some had extending parts, such as the part of "g"" that extends down. The only exception to this is "@" which had a width of 9, and for that I have found no reason.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, you've cleared up how `getlength()` works for me. I'm still confused as to what `getsize()` is measuring if it's not the offset nor the bounding box of the pixels (in which case `font.getsize(".")` would be much smaller).

Comment: getsize() usually is the bounding box, but in the case of italics, underline, etc., the bounding box and the size of the character can be different.

Comment: `getsize()` returns a width of 9 for `A`, `Q`, `V`, `X`, `Y`, `%`, `&`, `@` and `_`. Strange.

Comment: That is strange! Perhaps, the values are not exactly 8, but instead they are 8.3, 8.6 etc, and they round the values, but I am not sure. I went through the ImageFont.py file again but that doesn't help, only makes it more confusing.